# Modified N Queens with placed queen

Tags: java, n-queens

I'm creating an N Queens problem solver with Backtracking. The twist however is that the first queen is placed by the user and then the backtracking is run to process the other 7 queens. My program functions to fulfill this task and the backtracking is functional however I can only place the queen on the first left column as the parameter the function takes is the column to start the backtracking procedure on.

Board class

```
 public boolean solveQueen(int col) { 
     if (col >= board.length) {  
         printBoard();
         System.out.println("queen");
         return true; 
     }

     for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
         if (notUnderAttack(i, col)) {
             placeQ(i, col);
             solveQueen(col + 1);
             removeQ(i, col);  
         }

     return false;         
 }
```

Main class

```
queen.placeQ(0, 2);
queen.solveQueen(3);
queen.printBoard();
```

To solve this I've tried wrapping around the first queen and starting the backtracking a column after the initial placement but the problem here is that whilst it places the queens at 3,4,5,6,7 column and the preplaced queen is at the 2nd column the first column has no queens. I'm not quite sure how to add the queen in the first column. I've tried using modulo but I'm not sure if I've implemented that correctly so I removed it.

```
public boolean notUnderAttack(int row, int col) {    
    if ((rowCheck(row) == false) || (colCheck(col) == false) || (diagonalCheck(row, col) == false)) {
        return false; 
    }
    return true; 
}
```

Comment: Hi. I just moved a line of code that was accidentally in the text into the code block it belonged in. PS Don't compare booleans to truth values, just use them. Also use `!` instead of `== false`. So notUnderAttack is just `return rowCheck(row) && colCheck(col) && diagonalCheck(row, col)`. But "check" communicates nothing. Name booleans for when they are true. Also putting "not" in a name complicates. "!" in front of the true case instead even saves 2 characters. (Joke. But not a joke.) So UnderAttack is just `return rowUnderAttack(row) || colUnderAttack(col) || diagonalUnderAttack(row, col)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either store the column of the initial queen and then skip that column `solveQueen`. or. create a method that check for a queen in the column already and skips based on that. And then always just call `solveQueen(1)` The first solution is good (more efficient) if you only ever want to place the 1st queen. Second is better if you may expand this to handle multiple placed initial queens.

Comment: So, from what I understand I just try to skip out the column the queen is on? Would that be an if statement where I track the column from another queen place function specifically used to place the queen and then use an if statement inside to just skip the statement?

Comment: yes basically the first line of solveQueen should be like` if (col == firstQueenCol){ solvequeen(col+1);}` or instead of col==fQCol you can make it call a method that returns boolean if there is a queen in the col already.

Comment: Mhm, tried it out and it works perfectly, only problem is that since the column isn't being placed and is instead skipped I found that the previous rows have diagonal conflicts so I'm guessing it's due to the fact that it doesn't preemptively detect the placed queen. I'll need another if statement from what I'm guessing to exclude this answer from the series of solutions I'm guessing?

Comment: yeah maybe show the content of notUnderAttack(). you may need to modify that method to check all cols instead of just all previous cols

Comment: Added inside main message, for now it's the diagonal checks which seem to be not working as the col/row ones are functioning fine

Comment: I've tried this as a possible solution to have the diagonal check to include all rows instead of specific ones however to no avail does it seem to be working. Instead of calling the rows and colums I've tried to just traverse like how I've done in column/row checks. Added the attempt to create diagonal traversal into the main thread

Comment: Your first solution on the diagonal is like this >q and does nothing over here. make 2 more loops where you do +i+j and -i+j and you will have >q<

Comment: Ok that makes a lot more sense now and after testing it everything is working fine now, thank you so much!

Comment: @JuliusVelvet up toot  my answer plox :)